# Google Maps addGeoJson Based on Viewport

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am loading 10,000 polygons using `map.data.addGeoJson` technique in a map all at once — so obviously it takes a while to load them based on the RAM of the computer.

How can I make them load based on the viewport of the computer screen? And load the rest when `bounds_changed` event is fired?

Comment: Do you have the ability to generate the GeoJSON on the fly or to separate out the polygons so you can load them separately? Are they in a database?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not in the database. I'm testing this locally and `map.data.addGeoJson` simply points to where the local JSON file is stored.

Comment: You need to break up your JSON file somehow.  How are you planning on doing that?

Comment: @geocodezip I don't know how to break it up. How can I tile the JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

Depends for example  if you have also stored the center of the poligon you can query the polygon with the center inside of the bounds of the viewport of the computer screen. 
Get the bounds is not a problem you can use

```
 map.getBounds();
```

The real problem is how you can query the polygon who satisfied the condition for a correct select.

Comment: I do have the centroid of the polygon as part of the properties in my GeoJSON file. So you're saying to read the centroids and make them fit within the bounds of the viewport?

Comment: You if you can easily query the polygon based on their centroid can easily select only the polygons that are to be displayed in that window. To view should you increase slightly the size of the bound as there may be polygons with the centroid falling slightly outside the bound and lying on the edge but that it is right that they appear.

With these techniques by selecting from populations of 100,000 polygons in conditions of high zoom you are to display only a few hundred or a few thousand polygons for a time so with very very good performance.

Comment: Do you have an example that I can follow? Going to give it a try but no idea how to start.

Comment: The problem is how you can query the centroid, where are stored the information? The example is too big is not easy  examinate it

Comment: The centroid is stored as "property" as part of the JSON file. Can't I use something like `viewPort.contains(polyCentroids)` in Google Maps -- where viewPort is the bounding box.

Comment: I don't think you can query the viewport in this manner. Instead, I believe that you have to query the JSON file. Ie on the server you have to have a function to examine the archive JSON and make the selection on the centroid that interest you. I think you should use a technique to that used by the database eqivalente nonSQL when making selections on the structures JSON.
In some projects where I could not use geographic databases I imported polygons and their properties to database tables just to be able to perform queries on this data.

Comment: In your case I think you can just use NoSQL databases and their ability to work on structures JSON.